# How to return data from getClipboardData?

Tags: vba, compiler-errors

```
Private Sub importClipboard_Click()
    Dim data As Collection
    data = getClipboardData()
    ...do something...
End Sub

Function getClipboardData() As Collection
    ...do something...    
End Function
```

I get

> Compile error:
>   Argument not optional"

on the line:

```
data = getClipboardData()
```

There no arguments to the `getClipboardData()` function - so how can I be missing one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a bad error message, but your problem is a common one - you've got to put `Set data = getClipboardData()` as you're returning an object.